# error in mysql CREATE TABLE `mms_14082423_forum`.`posts`

Tags: mysql

SQL query:

```
CREATE TABLE  `----`.`posts` (

`id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY ,
`post` VAR CHAR( 1000 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
`date` VAR CHAR( 1000 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
`file path ` VAR CHAR( 1000 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE = MY ISM ;

MySQL said: Documentation

#1067 - Invalid default value for 'post'
```

What is the error here ? I don't think I did anything wrong

Comment: Default value CANNOT be `NULL` if you are defining the column as `NOT NULL`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when post field is NOT NULL then it cannot contain default NULL value.

```
CREATE TABLE  `posts` (

`id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY ,
`post` VARCHAR( 1000 ) NOT NULL ,
`date` VARCHAR( 1000 ) NOT NULL ,
`filepath` VARCHAR( 1000 ) NOT NULL
) ENGINE = MYISAM ;
```